# importNode before LastChild

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to paste an XML file into a ``main'' XML. I have tried this using the following code:

```
XmlNode node = xmldoc.ImportNode(secondXmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild, true);
xmldoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);
```

Now, my last child is `</Document>`but I want to paste the other XML one child before that one. Is it possible to go back one child?

> UPDATE

I tried to use the insertBefore like this:

```
XmlDocument main = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument toMain = new XmlDocument();
main.Load(path);
toMain.Load(path);

XmlNode node = main.ImportNode(toMain.DocumentElement, true);
XmlNode refNode = main.SelectSingleNode("/ObjectList"); 
main.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(node, refNode);
main.Save(path);
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
......
......
<ObjectList>insert toMain here</ObjectList>
</Document> // end of XML file
```

> UPDATE 2

Apperently, SelecSingleNode gave me a `null` reference, this had something to do with the namespace. Now it is working.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`InsertBefore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertbefore.aspx), passing the node you want to insert before.

Eg.

```
xmldoc.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(newNode, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);
```

Comment: I already accepted your solution. But what if I want to go back two or three childs?

Comment: @user3185388 You need to pass the node you want to insert before to the API (or use `InsertAfter` with the node before). It becomes a matter of getting a reference to the relative node: there are lots of ways to do this depending on requirements but you would need to define the document and those requirements to work that out (and that is beyond the scope of an edit to an existing Q on [SO]).

Comment: I updated my question, still havent figured it out, checked a lot of other topics, but those didnt work out for me